# Node.js install fails on Windows 10 1803

Tags: node.js, windows, installation

I finished my PC today and I wanted to install node.js on it. 
But for some weird reason, it is saying "Copying files" and then after a few seconds, it says "Rolling back". I can't think of a reason why it is not installing. Windows is Windows 10 "Spring Update" 1803.

https://youtu.be/-OXGGWC41vE

Here's a proof, in form of a unlisted video on Youtube.

Thanks in advance.

Niklas

Comment: Instead of videos that can't be copied and executed post what you actually did, what commands you used and what happened. If there are logs, post them as well. *Did* you check the installation logs?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same problems in win 10 system but i was able to install it by doing following steps:

--- Disable ur antivirus it might be blocking node event tracer

--- Disable installation of all components as shown in image below

[installation file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8v2A.png)

-- complete installation

-- After installation again go to setup and enable components one by one and install , leave out performance counter

-- After all components are installed code to cmd and do node -v u will see it works

Comment: Nice and pragmatic!

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here, but after some research of old same problem, found to **install without ETW (Event tracing) or without Performance Counters** (during the installation you can select those options under Node.js runtime branch), but I got some new errors when npm install/npm run dev, some with node-sass issues.

**EDIT:** Ok, so my problem was directly with my antivirus (Avast), I've been reading that with AVG there is the same problem, then you can install it without getting rid of ETW or PC.

Answer (score 0):

A batch script (within //nodejs/node_modules/npm) is no longer supported on Windows 10, version 1803. This file does not properly copy over **(this is NOT a hard drive issue but rather an issue with this version of Windows 10!)**.

File(s) affected:

- \nodejs\node_modules\npm\make.bat **(This file *alone* requires a reboot.)**

Copying this file over from the Zip archive IS possible, but requires a reboot to get out of the copy prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (On windows 10 1909). You can work around this by installing Node.js using Chocolatey instead https://chocolatey.org/packages/nodejs.install

Open Powershell elevated and run the following command:

```
choco install nodejs.install
```

That worked for me when everything else did not!

> Note that `choco` is a Chocolatey command (it is like `npm`). If you don't already have Chocolatey already installed, go to https://chocolatey.org/install and get the install command.

Answer (score 0):

Just disabled your antivirus first before installing!